# Short term disability and FIT taxable wages

Tags: united-states, income-tax

From what I read, Short Term Disability (STD) sometimes is  taxable income and sometimes not. I was on STD earlier this year, and from my paystub, I see the STD was included in the "Total wages" but *not* the "FIT taxable wages". Does that mean, in my case, my STD income is the non-taxable kind?

I did come across this related [Q&A](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/46454/are-short-term-disability-payments-taxed), but in my case I am unsure how to determine whether the disability plan is paid with after tax dollars or not.

I am in California, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if your STD premiums were paid with after tax money (i.e.: if the amount you paid for the coverage was included in your taxable income at the time). If so then the benefit is not taxable.

You can check that looking at your payslips where the deductions for the benefit are being made. If the deduction reduced FIT on that payslip then it wasn't taxed, and the benefit should be taxed. If the deduction didn't reduce FIT then it was taxed and the benefit shouldn't be taxed.

From what you've described it sounds like the deduction was included in FIT, and so the benefit isn't. But it's your responsibility to confirm.